# mysql select min and max year for consecutive group by

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
Bike
+----+--------+---------+------+
| id | make   | model   | year |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 1  | make-z | model-1 | 2010 |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 2  | make-z | model-1 | 2011 |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 3  | make-z | model-1 | 2012 |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 4  | make-z | model-1 | 2013 |
+----+--------+---------+------+
| 5  | make-z | model-1 | 2014 |
+----+--------+---------+------+


Part
+--------+-------+-------+----------+
| id     | name  | price | category |
+--------+-------+-------+----------+
| part-A | spg-A | 10.00 | Spring   |
+--------+-------+-------+----------+
| part-B | spg-B | 12.00 | Spring   |
+--------+-------+-------+----------+

Link
+--------+--------+
| bikeID | partID |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | part-A |
+--------+--------+
| 2      | part-A |
+--------+--------+
| 3      | part-A |
+--------+--------+
| 4      | part-B |
+--------+--------+
| 5      | part-A |
+--------+--------+
```

I need to build an application chart that shows which parts fit which bike.

The problem I have is that:

model-1  years 2010 - 2012 and 2014 uses part-A

model-1  year 2013  uses part-B

So the min and max miss the fact that 2013 is not included.

I need to get the min and max for consecutive years only.

```
SELECT *, MIN(year) AS syear, MAX(year) AS eyear 
FROM bike
LEFT JOIN link ON bike.id = link.bikeID
LEFT JOIN part ON link.partID = part.id 
WHERE part.category = 'spring'
GROUP BY make, model, part.id
ORDER BY make, model, year
```

The output I get is:

```
+---------+--------+------+------+
| model-1 | part-A | 2010 | 2014 |
+---------+--------+------+------+
| model-1 | part-B | 2013 | 2013 |
+---------+--------+------+------+
```

What it should look like:

```
+---------+--------+------+------+
| model-1 | part-A | 2010 | 2012 |
+---------+--------+------+------+
| model-1 | part-B | 2013 | 2013 |
+---------+--------+------+------+
| model-1 | part-A | 2014 | 2014 |
+---------+--------+------+------+
```

I typed this out as a simple example of what I'm needing to do.

The id's in the table are not in order, nor are the parts.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you want consecutive year, why do you `MIN()` and `MAX()` year?  This will return the minumum and maximum year, not the consecutive year.

Comment: I want the min and max for consecutive years only - so in the example I give for part-A there is no 2013 so it fits 2010 - 2012 does not fit 2013 but does fit 2014. The Min and Max grouping is giving we 2010 - 2014 (which is right in the sql) but wrong in the real world at part-A does not fit 2013.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for that - question updated.

Comment: ...but not in the manner requested :-(